# Facebook Open Graph Beta - Can't create action because I already use it

Tags: open-graph-beta

The new Open Graph beta is telling me that I cannot use the action 'want' or the object 'item'

I have used them in previous applications, however these have since been deleted and I've created a new application where I cannot use it.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Telling me the action is "already defined" even though it WAS defined and then deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the types are not defined in the namespace you're using (or they were restricted to the app that defined them). If the types have not been created within the new application, you probably should use the Get Started tool that's available in the Open Graph section on the [app control](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) panel to create you Action and Object types.